# How to set up a default image

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Before i click the image to pull the camera, i want to set up a default image on the imageview that shows a http://www.inc.com/images/avatar/default1.gif to inform that in that imageview goes a person image.

What is the best way to do this procedure?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a UIImageView the first thing is to create a UIImage object using this code

```
UIImage *defaultImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"];
```

And then pass it to the UIImageView object if it is a property of your view controller you can use this(imageView is the variable name of UIImageView)

```
self.imageView.image = defaultImage;
```

If you are instantiating a new UIImageView in your view controller you can use this

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:defaultImage];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImageView *theImageView;
//assuming that's the declaration in your header

//make sure default1.gif is inside your application bundle

//copied into the resources folder of your xcode project

//this code goes into your -viewDidLoad method

theImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"default1.gif"];
```